# How would a galactic republic function?

Tags: star-wars

How would a galactic republic as seen in Star Wars function?

Assuming each world had a representative senator, what would they vote on?

How could they enforce or make laws for such a wide array of worlds outside of trade deals?

Comment: Sounds a bit broad. You might want to consider asking this on chat.

Comment: Poorly. VERY poorly. Until an efficient ruler arises above all and restores Order to the Galaxy.

Comment: This is a question about speculative politics that is unrelated to a specific work of fiction (not “How does the Galactic Republic function?” but “How would a galactic republic really function?”)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple: have a look at how European Union works!

Plenty of expensive bureaucrats detached from the problems of normal people, a wide Senate with ever changing majorities and weak powers, states vetoing everything in turn, de facto paralyzing whatever initiative, petty fights, over-complex voting / representation systems, very very very slow responses to urgent problems, lots of talk and no facts, etc.

Comment: Great analogy, but who's Palpatine?!

Comment: Oh no! let's leave the this level of politics (who's Palpatine and similar) out of this place..;-)

Comment: They had instant communication within the galaxy. It was called the HoloNet, as it could send holograms as well as 2-d images.  We see the holograms several times over the course of the movies.

Comment: As Kevin noted, due to Holonet's availability, I removed the last paragraph discussing STL communications impact. +1 otherwise

Comment: I guess UN is a better candidate for comparison

Comment: @DVK Except there doesn't seem to be an analogue of the Security Council in the Republic where a handful of states can veto a majority vote of the rest of the senate.

Comment: Even with instant communication the Republic was perpetually shown to be helpless in the face of localized problems, inter-member skirmishing, slavery, and single planet tragedy.  They were as equipped to deal with such conflicts as well as the US Senate can deal with the pothole in front of my house.  They might be able to pass a billion dollar road maintenance bill, but it may not fix my problem.

Comment: I think the UN, minus the Security Council and plus a few thousand additional self-serving factions, is probably the most appropriate analog to the Galactic Senate. Until the events of the prequel trilogy, each individual faction had its own army, and the Republic in itself didn't have a standing army; it simply formed what it needed from a combination of the Jedi and from cooperating factions. The ability of any one faction to derail efforts of the majority through endless procedural technicalities is also seen, as is the watering-down of the Republic's official position on anything.

Answer (score 1):

You see it in the movie. One senator or the other, or the Chancellor, bring an issue they care about to a vote. More likely than not (though not in G-canon), most stuff, as in the typical human parlament, first gets discussed in some Committee. Then the Senate votes on it (after lots of speeches).